# Select First, Max, and Last non-null value per group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to select, per group, the first and last values (chronologically) as well as the max value. I had written a query that works fine except it does not handle the `NULL` values.  I need it to ignore `NULL` values.

Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @T table (
    LabName VARCHAR(20)
,   CreatedOn   date
,   LabValue    int
)

INSERT INTO @T
        ( LabName,CreatedOn,LabValue )
VALUES
    ('Creatinine', '2016-01-01',    NULL)
,   ('Creatinine', '2016-02-01',    15)
,   ('Creatinine', '2016-03-01',    20)
,   ('Creatinine', '2016-04-01',    19)
,   ('SGOT (ST)', '2016-01-01', 25)
,   ('SGOT (ST)', '2016-02-01', 31)
,   ('SGOT (ST)', '2016-03-01', 25)
,   ('SGOT (ST)', '2016-04-01', NULL)

SELECT DISTINCT 
*
FROM (
    SELECT
        LabName
    ,   FIRST_VALUE(LabValue) OVER(PARTITION BY LabName ORDER BY CreatedOn ASC) AS FirstValue
    ,   MAX(LabValue) OVER(PARTITION BY LabName) AS MaxValue
    ,   LAST_VALUE(LabValue) OVER(PARTITION BY LabName ORDER BY CreatedOn ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) LastValue
    FROM @T
) AS T
```

It was working fine until I realized some labs aren't run on some dates.  Once I put some `NULL`s into the test data, the results for `First` and `Last` will include them.

Here is the result I get:

```
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+
|  LabName   | FirstValue | MaxValue | LastValue |
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| Creatinine | NULL       |       20 | 19        |
| SGOT (ST)  | 25         |       31 | NULL      |
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Here is the result I want:

```
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+
|  LabName   | FirstValue | MaxValue | LastValue |
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| Creatinine | 15         |       20 | 19        |
| SGOT (ST)  | 25         |       31 | 25        |
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: nice query.after why don't you put where condion like this. "From @t where labvalue is not null"

Comment: Hi KumarHarsh - I put a comment below addressing this.  Basically, I made the example a little too simple.  What you suggest would indeed work if there were only the one labvalue.  In the real query i need to do this for multiple columns (labvalue1, labvalue2, labvalue3, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT LabName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_asc = 1 THEN LabValue END) as FirstValue,
       MAX(LabValue) as MaxValue, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_desc = 1 THEN LabValue END) as LastValue
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LabName
                                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN LabValue IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
                                         CreatedOn
                               ) as seqnum_asc,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LabName
                                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN LabValue IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
                                         CreatedOn DESC
                               ) as seqnum_desc
      FROM @T t
     ) T
GROUP BY LabName;
```

Comment: That was fast.  This works perfect, Thanks!  One minor correction is the second criteria in ORDER BY needs to be CreatedOn, not LabValue.  I switched those and I get the expected result.

Comment: @Bostaevski . . . Yes, I see.

Answer (score 2):

As you said there are 13 such columns  where you need to check not null values.

I think you should first filter all not null values using CTE,then using CTE you can write your actual query.CTE will reduce your result set and applying window function on reduce resultset will give better performance.

BTW,13 such columns appear t be bad DB design.you may have to 100 query in future.
IMHO, DISTINCT often indicate bad DB design than query.

```
;With CTE as
(-- try to reduce resultset if possible
SELECT * FROM @T
WHERE LabValue IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT DISTINCT 
*
FROM (
    SELECT
        LabName
    ,   FIRST_VALUE(LabValue) OVER(PARTITION BY LabName ORDER BY CreatedOn ASC) AS FirstValue
    ,   MAX(LabValue) OVER(PARTITION BY LabName) AS MaxValue
    ,   LAST_VALUE(LabValue) OVER(PARTITION BY LabName ORDER BY CreatedOn ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) LastValue
    FROM CTE
) AS T
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database is handling `NULL` values properly.
First value for `Creatinine` is actually null and last value for `SGOT (ST)` is null as well.
If you wish to discard rows with null values just add it in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
*
FROM (
    SELECT
        LabName
    ,   FIRST_VALUE(LabValue) OVER(PARTITION BY LabName ORDER BY CreatedOn ASC) AS FirstValue
    ,   MAX(LabValue) OVER(PARTITION BY LabName) AS MaxValue
    ,   LAST_VALUE(LabValue) OVER(PARTITION BY LabName ORDER BY CreatedOn ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) LastValue
    FROM @T
    WHERE LabValue IS NOT NULL
) AS T;
```

Comment: Hi Kamil - I considered this however I sort of over-simplified the question.  There are actually 13 columns I need to perform this on.  In context of how I framed the question it would be like having a table with LabValue1, LabValue2, LabValue3..... LabValue13.

Comment: The way I framed the question, though, your solution also works